# Wrong action triggered when pressing enter in QMenu

Tags: python, pyqt5, contextmenu

I have a context menu with a checkbox and a spinbox. Both work as expected, except that when I am typing a number in the spinbox, I tend to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to close the menu, but that also toggles the checkbox. Does anyone know how to prevent that?

minimal example:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFrame, QMenu, QAction, QWidgetAction, QFormLayout, QSpinBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

t = True
v = 0


class SpinAction(QWidgetAction):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(SpinAction, self).__init__(parent)
        w = QWidget()
        layout = QFormLayout(w)
        self.spin = QSpinBox()
        layout.addRow('value', self.spin)
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setDefaultWidget(w)


def _menu(position):
    menu = QMenu()
    test_action = QAction(text="Test", parent=menu, checkable=True)
    test_action.setChecked(t)
    test_action.toggled.connect(toggle_test)

    spin_action = SpinAction(menu)
    spin_action.spin.setValue(v)
    spin_action.spin.valueChanged.connect(spin_changed)

    menu.addAction(test_action)
    menu.addAction(spin_action)
    action = menu.exec_(w.mapToGlobal(position))


def toggle_test(val):
    global t
    t = val


def spin_changed(val):
    global v
    v = val


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QFrame()
w.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
w.customContextMenuRequested.connect(_menu)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget must accept focus, so a proper focus policy (`StrongFocus` or `WheelFocus`) must be set, but since it's a container you should also set the [focus *proxy*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocusProxy) to the spin, so that it will handle the focus for it.

In this way the keyboard navigation of the menu will also work properly by using arrows or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the spinbox.

The action also has to be set as the *active action* of the menu in order to prevent the menu to accept events that may trigger other actions, and a way to achieve that is to install an event filter on the spin and check for events that *should* make the widget action as the active one, like `FocusIn` and `Enter` event.

Note that this results in some unintuitive results from the UX perspective: by default, hovering a *normal* QAction makes it the active one, but the user might want to move the mouse away from the spinbox in order to edit it without having the mouse *on* it, and by doing it another action could become active; in the meantime the spin should still keep the focus for obvious reasons. The result is that the other action might seem visually selected while the spinbox has focus. There is no obvious solution for this, and that's why widgets used for QWidgetActions should always be chosen with care.

```
class SpinAction(QWidgetAction):
    FocusEvents = QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn, QtCore.QEvent.Enter
    ActivateEvents = QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.QEvent.Wheel)
    WatchedEvents = FocusEvents + ActivateEvents
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # ...
        w.setFocusPolicy(self.spin.focusPolicy())
        w.setFocusProxy(self.spin)
        self.spin.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.spin and event.type() in self.WatchedEvents:
            if isinstance(self.parent(), QtWidgets.QMenu):
                self.parent().setActiveAction(self)
            if event.type() in self.FocusEvents:
                self.spin.setFocus()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Note: the `obj == self.spin` condition is required since QWidgetAction already installs an event filter. A more elegant solution is to create a QObject subclass intended for that purpose only, and only overriding `eventFilter()`.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are on the right track, unfortunately it doesn't quite work. It does work when tabing through the controls until the spin box, but if I just click in the spin box, edit the number and press enter, then the checkbox is toggled. I will have to investigate further

Comment: @DizietAsahi You're right, I didn't consider that. See the update.